# Autocomplete error, null is not an object, IE only

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

the following code works well in Chrome/FireFox, but error in IE. The error shows the message.

> Message: 'name' is null or not an
>   object

I know there are quite a few questions related. But they seem to be different in some way. So, please help. Thanks. (The error is occurred at line 7)

```
    $("#keywords").autocomplete('downloads/get_keywords', {
        multiple: true,
        parse: function(data) {
            return $.map(eval(data), function(row) {
                return {
                    data: row,
                    value: row.name, // error in here.
                    result: row.name
                };
            });
        },
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return format(item);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `downloads/get_keywords` returns?  I'm guessing there's some extra commas in there that only IE hates.

Comment: Thanks Ryley, you're right. I was focusing on the json script, but didn't check the data source that 'downloads/get_keywords' provides. Yes, IE hates the extra comma. Would you please answer my question? Then I can mark this solved.

Comment: Probably best to answer it yourself at this point (this is fine according to the FAQ) - show us what the bad data looked like and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed for quite a few months. Sorry for answering this late. Be careful for the autocomplete of jQuery, the data source of array should be clean without extra comma which is easily overlooked. In my question, "downloads/get_keywords" is a custom PHP function which returns the array listed in autocomplete drop-down box. But if you are using foreach to collect your array, you probably don't care about the extra comma at the end of array. But IE(only) hates the extra comma. To tackle this, just remove it than the problem is solved.

> $return_data = "";
>
> foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
>
> if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
>
> ```
>   $return_data .= "{ name: \"$key\", to: \"$value\" }, ";
> ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> $return_data =
>   substr_replace($return_data, '', -2);
>   // IE hates extra comma
>
> echo '[' . $return_data . ']';

Answer (score 1):

**Try to use these functions:**

```
function json_encode_string($in_str)
{
  mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
  $convmap = array(0x80, 0xFFFF, 0, 0xFFFF);
  $str = "";
  for($i=mb_strlen($in_str)-1; $i>=0; $i--)
  {
    $mb_char = mb_substr($in_str, $i, 1);
    if(mb_ereg("&#(\\d+);", mb_encode_numericentity($mb_char, $convmap, "UTF-8"), $match))
    {
      $str = sprintf("\\u%04x", $match[1]) . $str;
    }
    else
    {
      $str = $mb_char . $str;
    }
  }
  return $str;
}

function php_json_encode($arr)
{
  $json_str = "";
  if(is_array($arr))
  {
    $pure_array = true;
    $array_length = count($arr);
    for($i=0;$i<$array_length;$i++)
    {
      if(! isset($arr[$i]))
      {
        $pure_array = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if($pure_array)
    {
      $json_str ="[";
      $temp = array();
      for($i=0;$i<$array_length;$i++)       
      {
        $temp[] = sprintf("%s", php_json_encode($arr[$i]));
      }
      $json_str .= implode(",",$temp);
      $json_str .="]";
    }
    else
    {
      $json_str ="{";
      $temp = array();
      foreach($arr as $key => $value)
      {
        $temp[] = sprintf("\"%s\":%s", $key, php_json_encode($value));
      }
      $json_str .= implode(",",$temp);
      $json_str .="}";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(is_string($arr))
    {
      $json_str = "\"". json_encode_string($arr) . "\"";
    }
    else if(is_numeric($arr))
    {
      $json_str = $arr;
    }
    else
    {
      $json_str = "\"". json_encode_string($arr) . "\"";
    }
  }
  return $json_str;
}
```

---

### **And the code:**

```
echo php_json_encode($MyObject);
// The var "$MyObject" is what you want to encode as json
// If you're using PHP >= 5.20, you'll have this function implemented as "json_encode"
```